# Eclipse RCP - good Eclipse Forms tutorial/resource

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm looking for resources to learn how to use effectively Eclipse forms within an Eclipse RCP application. I was trying to use the newest SWT Window Builder plugin on Indigo but building forms this way doesn't really work for me eg. cannot put anything inside expandable composite etc.  (I have Swing background with Netbeans designer) and I'm new to SWT. 
All I can find so far is [this quite old tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html) from 2005.
Any help, point to good tutorial/book/source code sample will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much changed actually since the old 2005 tutorial so it's still very usable.
Check these out in addition too:

- [Eclipse Forms: New in 3.3](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Forms33/index.html)
- [DeveloperWorks article on making forms Web-like](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-forms/)

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Thanks Max, I have already figured it out, I have discovered that I have a bigger problem with SWT layouts then as with forms in general :), bug I haven't seen the page on the second link you provided, so thanks!

Comment: The pages in these link are deprecated kindly take them off

Answer (score 8):

I've found http://www.vogella.de/ to be invaluable.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseForms/article.html seems to be the most relevant article.

Answer (score 0):

I've also got the hint to start with vogella but after the first 2 topics I realized It's to hard to start with.

What helped me much more was to create each example/sample project and look for the source. Once you understood how all works you can lookup at vogella what you exactly need.

Comment: Where did you create sample project from?