# What are the alternatives to SWT TabFolder?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I'm looking for a component that contains items which can be selected to show their client areas, to be used on an Eclipse RCP application.

SWT *TabFolder* and *CTabFolder* would be the first choices, but I want to try out some alternatives.

There's SWT *ExpandBar* and I've read about [Nebula Pshelf](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/pshelf/pshelf.php).

Can you tell me some other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build your own alternative using a [StackLayout](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StackLayout.html) and some control(s) to switch between  the different "panels." Here's a [simple example SWT Snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet249.java).

If you wanted to build an Eclipse Forms UI, you could use ExpandableComposite. See:

- http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html - about half-way down it talks about ExpandableComposite.
- http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseForms/article.html
- [Eclipse RCP - good Eclipse Forms tutorial/resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731477/eclipse-rcp-good-eclipse-forms-tutorial-resource)

Answer (score 1):

I can only add the JFace Forms widgets to your list, which include ExpandableComposite and Section, see this [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html)

But I like CTabFolder most. It has some nice options like the optional topRight Control or even customizable CTabFolderRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the Eclipse Forms' [ScrolledPageBook](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/forms/widgets/ScrolledPageBook.html), which can integrate with other RCP/SWT components.